# According to CCES, how did young voters identify in each state in terms of partisanship in 2016 and 2022?

Tags: united-states, demographics

How did voters under 30 identify (excluding independents and others) in each state in 2022 and 2016, and how does that compare to partisan identification among all voters in those years? I am asking because I want to see if young voters became more Democratic over time. I want to see it state-by-state to see if there are any regional trends. This comes from an [older question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65794/how-red-or-blue-is-each-state-by-self-described-partisan-identification-per-cc) that I asked here.

Notes: The source for CCES is [here](https://cces.gov.harvard.edu/). I am excluding independents because they cannot be decoded in terms of partisan identification.